# Send Email with attachment using scheduler in ODOO

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Scheduler should generate a report and save it in ir.attachments, i.e PDF report should be stored in ir.attachment table, then need to send mail with that report as attachments.

1) How to store the report (PDF) in ir.attachment table

In ODOO 9

So far I tried:

```
@api.model
def _redmine_mail(self):

    ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data']
    try:
        template_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('pms', 'email_template_edi_timesheet')[1]
        print template_id
    except ValueError:
        template_id = False
    try:
        compose_form_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('mail', 'email_compose_message_wizard_form')[1]
    except ValueError:
        compose_form_id = False
    ctx = dict()
    ctx.update({
        'default_model': 'redmine.timesheet',
        'default_res_id': 1,
        'default_use_template': bool(template_id),
        'default_template_id': template_id,
        'default_composition_mode': 'comment',
        'mark_so_as_sent': True
    })

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
        'views': [(compose_form_id, 'form')],
        'view_id': compose_form_id,
        'target': 'new',
        'context': ctx,
    }
```

The _redmine_mail is triggered via Scheduler.

1) How to generate the report and store it in ir.attachents ?
2) No need to open the email wizard, mail should be directly send with attachment of report.

Thanks in Advance